# Is it possible to wrap code in a block to execute whole block while calling one variable?

Tags: vbscript

I have few lines of code I would like to execute in my script on a couple of occasions.

```
objFSO.CreateTextFile (path & statFile)
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile (path & statFile, 8)
objFile.Write strLine
objFile.Close
```

Is it possible to assign a variable (or something) to it, so I don't have to write all 4 lines all the time?

I know about conditional statements, but there is really no condition. On the other hand I could try to cheat `IF` by using it with something always true. 
Can I even assign to, let's say, `a` something like `= if...then`?

Comment: [Declare a sub](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx9ceb2w(v=vs.84).aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the re-usable code in a [Sub (or a Function)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx9ceb2w%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

```
>> Sub CalledOften()
>>   WScript.Echo "Here I am again"
>> End Sub
>> For i = 1 To 3
>>     CalledOften
>> Next
>>
Here I am again
Here I am again
Here I am again
```

Comment: Great. I'm so green with scripting that I haven't noticed I've been using Subs all along:) But can I call a sub from within a sub or does it have to be on a same level?

Comment: @Mykail In VBScript all procedures and functions must be defined in the global scope (nested definitions in other procedures/functions are not allowed), so you can call any procedure/function from any other procedure/function.

Comment: On the other hand this is to be avoided, mostly. Function calls are slow, inline code is fast. A optimising compiler will undo what was suggested, a function, and inline your code. In VBScript you have to do that yourself. Ctrl + C and Ctrl + V can cut and paste lines.

Comment: @Trigger That would result in nearly impossible to maintain spaghetti code. Don't *ever* do this! If performance is that much of an issue VBScript isn't the right language in the first place.